# How to connect to in-premise LDAP or consume LDAP type destination in cloud foundry using Java

Tags: java, ldap, cloud-foundry

im migrating a java (jersey) api application from SAP cloud NEO to sap cloud CF (cloud foundry).
in CF you need to use the connectivity service to get a jwt token and use it to authentication against the cloud connector which you then use to open a connection to the on-premise server.
the are several way i know that i can achieve that.

1. use the destination service to populate the properties for ldap connection
2. use TCP type connection with SOCK5 protocol.
3. some custom SocketFactory that might use one of the other option i wrote.

i read all king of documentations (provided below) but none of them works or demonstrate a complete code example.

in CF Destination there is an LDAP type configuration but i'm not sure on how to consume it and make it work in my code.

i will appreciate any help from someone who already establish a working connection to on-premise Domain server using Java and Jersey. (not Spring).
thanks in advance.

[image]

Below are some reference to resource i used:

https://help.sap.com/docs/connectivity/sap-btp-connectivity-cf/connectivityconfiguration-api

https://help.sap.com/docs/connectivity/sap-btp-connectivity-cf/using-tcp-protocol-for-cloud-applications